# Apply_along_axis and Dask Arrays

Tags: python, dask

I have a question about the shape of Dask Array after using apply_along_axis method:

```
import dask.array as da
array = da.from_array(np.array([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], \
                                [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]), \
                      chunks=(2,2))
```

Now if

```
a = da.apply_along_axis((lambda x: x/sum(x)), axis=0, arr=array)
```

then

```
a.shape == (1,4)
```

but

```
a.compute().shape == (4,4)
```

Is this correct? I think that `a.shape` should also be `(4,4)`.